# Selenium ChromeDriver Client Certificate support

Tags: ssl, google-chrome-extension, selenium-webdriver, client-certificates

Do Selenium ChromeDrive has any support for sites demanding Client Certificates?
Can it record or replay those certificates pop-ups?